# easy_install eggs not importing on my mac

Tags: python, macos, easy-install

I've got python 2.6 up and running on the ol' macbook, but for whatever reason my easy_installs aren't importing correctly.

```
WAT DO? pwd
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages

WAT DO? ls
Django-1.2.1-py2.6.egg
PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
README
easy-install.pth
pyserial-2.5-py2.6.egg

WAT DO? echo $PATH
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/django:/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/X11/bin

WAT DO? python
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named serial
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed other versions of python on you machine? What is the output of `import math` and `print math.__file__`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what easy_install's problem with PySerial is, but I decided to try an alternative route. Just installed from source. Works.

Comment: Hmm. It worked on my linux box (ubuntu), but still can't figure out the mac side.